# Caution when using symfony 4 console with docker

Tags: symfony, docker

I used docker to set a web stack for symfony 4 . I executed a php container with this command :

```
 winpty docker exec -ti 8c6 bash
```

In this image i installed my symfony 4 project, i generated an entity and i tried :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Every time i tried to execute a command with symfony console i receive this message:

```
[CAUTION] This operation should not be executed in a production environment!
```

how to avoid this caution and is it a security problem ?

Comment: Sooo, what seems to be a problem with that?

Comment: how to avoid this caution and is it a security problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a command should be executed with `--force` argument:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --force`

Read more here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema